# Weird PHP error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end" under windows but not under linux

Tags: php, windows, linux

I've developped a script under linux which works perfectly, the

```
php -l
```

command says there is no error and indeed it executes normally. But whenever I try to run it under WAMP I get a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

message pointing to the very end of the file! I search but I don't find any error, the PHP versions are the same in the two machines! Have you any idea on what can make a script run on a linux server and not on a windows one?

Comment: as suggested about the }, use an text editor with PHP syntax highlighting to figure out where the missing one is.

Comment: the script would be very helpful, if the answer of @andreswinter does not help you, try to strip the confidential parts so can look at the script anyway!

Comment: As Andreas says it means there's a missing } the error messages could be being suppressed on one environment and not on the other, giving you different messages.

Comment: @Dale Nope, `php -l` would give you a syntax error regardless of display_errors and error_reporting settings. Anyway, it's likely just a missing `}`, perhaps do a diff on both files, because there *is* a difference.

Comment: Ah I didn't know about php -l Thanks Berry, learn something new everyday.

Comment: Thanks for all, I reviewed the script line by line, I even counted the number of {,(,[ and compared them with the number of },),] there is no error in the syntax! If there was an error it would be displayed by php -l am I right?

Comment: Is it possible that linux blind eye to this type of errors!?

Comment: @BerryLangerak a diff gives no difference, I copied/past the script

Comment: did you copy/past all files? maybe there's an include that's causing problems? if the script is an exact copy it has to be something in the setup. Did you compare the php.ini files? and maybe just as an experiment try to convert the unix linebreaks to windows linebreaks (for example with notepad++)

Comment: I knew it ;) . Shorttags are non-standard and have to be enabled in the php.ini. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: Btw, if you make an addendum to your question, it is best to add it _afterwards_, so the original question still makes sense for new users `:-)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it! There was a `<?` inside the code to display html ^^ it must be `<?php`. I wonder why windows do not know a PHP file from the `<?` tag!

Comment: @ubungu: Because you have configured it to not know that php-tag. That simple it is. Learn how to configure PHP, see http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: You might see this when moving from a local server to a production server or vice versa.  I had short tags turned off in WAMP and wondered why when I copied my live server from a Linux Apache environment it broke one of the menu pages.  The reason is the theme uses short tags somewhere and these are enabled on the live server but not my localhost.  Simply editing php.ini on my WAMP server to turn on the tags "short_open_tag = On" fixed the problem.  My preferred fix is to leave the short tags off but that means updating the theme code and hence affects auto update of the theme.

Comment: I wondered why my plugin wouldn't work on a new host and it was because it didn't allow short tags for <? but my old host did

I searched through the file and found one case of using <? instead of <?php and fixed it. now everything works again!

Comment: Same problem here, had a hidden <? instead of <?php and although my server works many other did not. Thanks for reminding to look for that!

Answer (score 3):

This means you have forgot a `}` in your code or you forgot to close a string.

But don't ask where the error occurs, for this you need to post the code :)

Answer (score 2):

as Andreas wrote, this usually means that a block or a quote is not closed.

But you said, that the code runs fine under linux - so something must be different between the two setups...

maybe you use shorttags (`<?` instead of `<?php`) somewhere and don't have them enabled on the WAMP server?

the other big difference between unix and windows files usually are the linebreaks, but I can't think of a codeblock where linebreaks would cause this error only under windows

Comment: I user <?php ...code... ?> and a "hello world" script runs on both servers